# Trouble with my z variable (mips)

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

I'm taking a class where we learn mips and I'm a bit lost.

I'm supposed to: 
Add the values in memory locations a, b, and c; then subtract the value in d       from your subtotal and put the answer into memory location z.

But when I assemble my code I keep getting my z number wrong.

```
.data 

a: .word 1
b: .word 2
c: .word 2
d: .word 1
z: .word 1

.text

lw $s0, a
lw $s1, b
lw $s2, c
lw $s3, d


add $s2, $s0, $s1
add $s4, $s2, $s3

sub $s5, $s3, $s4

sw $s5, z
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Could someone push me in the right direction?
This is my results:

```
a should be 16 and is 16
b should be 7 and is 7
c should be 5 and is 5
d should be 15 and is 15
z should be 13 and is -23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add $s2, $s0, $s1
```

By doing this, you're overwriting the value of `c` you loaded in `s2`!

Either store the result of this calculation in `s0` or `s1`, or don't load `c` until you need it.